# Color index of conditionally formatted cell

Tags: excel, macros, conditional-formatting, vba

I have a sheet where there are some conditionally formatted cells. There are 2 rules per cell for red and blue colors. There is another sheet where I have a If formula in the macro which checks for the color in those conditionally formatted cells:

```
If Range("Q10").End(xlDown).Interior.ColorIndex = 33 Then
code
End If
```

But it seems that this code won't work as the cells are conditionally formatted. The macro runs without entering the If formula and goes directly to End If. How do I ensure that it works?

Thanks

Comment: nope you can't return the color index of a conditionally formatted cells using the above code. Eventhough conditional format colored the cell, but `.interior.colorindex` is still no color.

Comment: If it is 2010 or newer [DisplayFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838863.aspx) property of range should be used.

Comment: your `Range("Q10")` is not referneced with a `Worksheet` , so if you run this code when focus is on another sheet it won't ready the `Range` correctly. Instead, use `If Sheets("Your_Sheet_Name").Range("Q10").End(xlDown).Interior.ColorIndex = 33 Then`

Comment: If you use conditional formatting, why don't you apply the same logic used for the CF to identify the cells in VBA?

Comment: @teylyn Yes, I can use that but in some cells there are more than 2 rules and I will have to check for each rule. That kind of gets too long.

Comment: @BrakNicku Thanks for the suggestion. This solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to get the `Interior.Color` or `Interior.ColorIndex` of a cell that was formatted with Conditional Formatting.

### Code of a Generic Sub

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetFormatColor()

Dim CColor As Long
Dim CColorIndex As Long

' get the Color value of the first conditional formatting rule
CColor = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q10").FormatConditions(1).Interior.color

' get the ColorIndex value of the first conditional formatting rule
CColorIndex = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q10").FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex

End Sub
```

---

So, in your case, you need to find out which rule of the Conditional Formatting you are trying to look at. For example, let's say we want to check the `Cell.ColorIndex` of `Range("Q10")`, and the color is the first rule in the set of rules you have in your Conditonal Formatting.

**Code sample for this post**:

```
' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name, where you set-up the conditional formatting
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q10").FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 33 Then
    MsgBox "ColorIndex is : " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q10").FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex
End If
```

---

If you are using **Excel 2010** (or later), you can use the `DisplyFormat` property of a range, so you can use the code below:

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q10").DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 33 Then
    MsgBox "ColorIndex is : " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Q10").DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
End If
```